# How to find unique value in a MySQL Group By query?

Tags: mysql

> **MySQL TABLE :** `numbers`

```
+----+-----+------------+
| ID | NUM |   CREATED  |
+----+-----+------------+
| 1  | 11  | 2018-01-01 |
+----+-----+------------+
| 2  | 22  | 2018-02-01 |
+----+-----+------------+
| 3  | 11  | 2018-03-01 |
+----+-----+------------+
| 4  | 44  | 2018-04-01 |
+----+-----+------------+
| 6  | 44  | 2018-04-02 |
+----+-----+------------+
| 5  | 22  | 2018-05-01 |
+----+-----+------------+
```

In this table, `ID` is the **Primary Key**. `NUM` is the random value and `CREATED` is the **Date**.

> **My Query:**

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(CREATED,'%Y-%m') AS Month,
  COUNT(NUM) AS TotalNum,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(NUM)) AS UniqueNum
FROM
  `numbers`
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(CREATED,'%Y-%m')
```

> **Result of My Query:**

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| Month   | TotalNum | UniqueNum |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-01 |    1     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-02 |    1     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-03 |    1     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-04 |    2     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-05 |    1     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

> **But my Expected Result is :**

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| Month   | TotalNum | UniqueNum |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-01 |    1     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-02 |    1     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-03 |    1     |     0     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-04 |    2     |     1     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 2018-05 |    1     |     0     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

Result of `UniqueNum` should be `0` in Month **2018-03**. Because `NUM` 11 is already exists in Month **2018-01**. 
 Also 
Result of `UniqueNum` should be `0` in Month **2018-05** . Because `NUM` 22 already exists in Month **2018-02**.

I want to find the Unique number for every Month. How can I get my expected result by updating my **MySQL Query**? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to join the table to itself and return there only the numbers that don't exist with a previous CREATED date.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(n.CREATED,'%Y-%m') AS Month,
  COUNT(n.NUM) AS TotalNum,
  COUNT(un.NUM) AS UniqueNum
FROM
  `numbers` n
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, NUM FROM numbers n1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM numbers n2 WHERE n1.NUM = n2.NUM AND n2.CREATED < n1.CREATED)) un ON n.ID = un.ID 
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(n.CREATED,'%Y-%m')
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603850/1/0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This Query takes too much time when the number of rows are above 5K. Is there any other way to make Query faster? Please help

Comment: Please ask this in a separate question. Include the results of following queries: `show create table numbers\G` , `explain <query from my answer>;` , `show indexes from numbers;`

Comment: Problem is now solved by adding **INDEX** to `NUM` field. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that usually works for me is nested queries
Hope this helps

```
SELECT
    Month,
    SUM(NUMCNT) AS TotalNum,
    COUNT(NUM) AS UniqueNum
FROM
    (
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(CREATED,'%Y-%m') AS Month,
    NUM,
    COUNT(NUM) AS NUMcnt
FROM
    `numbers`
GROUP BY
    Month,
    NUM
) a
;
```